# Fields and quotient fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

We can define the quotient field in a *field* F as the equivalence relation:

$$(r,s)\sim (r',s') \Longleftrightarrow rs'-r's=0$$

where $r,r', s, s'\in F$ and $s,s'\neq0$.

I would like to know in this case if we can identify $(r,s)$ with $(rs^{-1},1)$, where $s^{-1}$ is the inverse of $s$ since $(r,s)\sim rs^{-1} \Longleftrightarrow r.1-rs^{-1}s=0$

To conclude, my intention is to know if we have fields we can work with $rs^{-1}$ instead of the abstract equivalence relation $\frac{r}{s}$.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you're saying is, given a field F, is it's field of fractions ($\equiv$ quotient field, it's just a name) $Frac(F)$ isomorphic to F? I'm just used to the notation Frac(F) for the "quotient field"/field of fractions/field of quotients.

The answer is yes for the reason you have pointed out. Let $\phi:Frac(F)\rightarrow F$
such that for $(a,b)\in Frac(F)$ $\;$ ($b\neq0$), $\;\phi((a,b))= ab^{-1}$. $\phi$ is an isomorphism of fields.

$\phi$ is well defined:

Let $(a,b), (c,d) \in Frac(F)$, with $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ ie $ad=bc$ or $ab^{-1}=cd^{-1}$, since b and d are non zero. Then $\phi((a,b))= ab^{-1}=cd^{-1}=\phi((c,d)).$

$\phi$ is 1-1:

Let $(a,b) \in Frac(F)$ s.t. $\phi((a,b))=0$, then $ab^{-1}=0, b\neq0 \implies a=0$. Since $(0,b)\sim(c,d) \iff c=0$, $ker( \phi )=\{0\}$. Hence $\phi$ is 1-1.

Finally $\phi$ is onto since $\phi((a,1))=a$.

"The field of fractions of a field is canonically isomorphic to the field itself."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions